# Rails + Google OpenID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openid

I'm trying to make my app use Google OpenID identifier. It should be exactly Google OpenID since I'll be using Google Chrome Web Store. I did some research but found no examples here.

The application uses Rails 3.2.

So is there any good example of how to accomplish that? Which gem should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [OmniAuth](http://www.omniauth.org), more specifically on its [OpenID strategy](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid).

Comment: I also found authlogic gem. Which one is better?

Comment: OmniAuth is the general library that supports many different authentication methods (Github, Twitter, OpenID....) and since you usually want to use only one, the library is divided into these sublibraries and you can choose which one you want.. So there's no choice for you to make, just use [OpenID](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-openid), it already depends on the correct version of OmniAuth.